# Make MSSQL data in a cell (from table a) clickable and retrieve data from table B in a new page

Tags: php, sql

I am new to php and trying to make something usefull for our office department. 
The info i want to show on page A is data from MSSQL table A. This is about the repair status 53.

The employee checks this list, clicks on the Document no (order) and gets more info about the specific order from table B. Table B has more info about the customer and the order.

I am struggling with the link that i can create.

Here the code below.

```
$query = "SELECT [Document No_],[Service Item No_],[Description],[Serial No_] FROM [dbo].[cache\$Service Item Line] WHERE [Repair Status Code] = '53'";
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params,$options);

if (!sqlsrv_num_rows($result)) {
    echo 'No records found';
} else {
    ?>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Servicenumber</th>
                <th>Service item</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Serialnumber</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo'<tr>'; 
                echo'<td>'. $row['Document No_']."</td>";
                echo'<td>'. $row['Service Item No_'].'</td>';
                echo'<td>'. $row['Description'].'</td>';
                echo'<td>'. $row['Serial No_'].'</td>';
                echo'<tr>';
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php 
}
?>
```

I need to add this code in php. In SQL it works fine, but when i add this to my php file, i got an internal server error when refreshing page

```
SELECT

     [Name]
    ,[Address]
    ,[Post Code]
    ,[City]
    ,[Your Reference]
    ,[No_]
    ,CASE SIL.[Claim]
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Ja'
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Nee'
        END

    [Claim]
FROM  [dbo].[cache\$Service Header] SH
    INNER JOIN [cache\$Service Item Line] SIL ON SH.[No_] = SIL.[Document No_]
WHERE [Repair Status Code] = '53'
```

Comment: what error you getting

Comment: @gaurav i don't get any errors. This shows me a table with data and thats ok, but i want that [document no_] is clickable. And when i click on it i have to go to a new page with info about that document no_.

i tried it this way: echo'<td>' <a href="test.php?id='.$row['Document No_'].'">'.$row['Document No_'].'</a>'</td>';

But this doesn't work because the code i use is not right. My first page does not display any content.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work with the code below. 
I will open a new topic for a new question.

```
$query = "SELECT SH.[Your Reference]
        ,SH.[Name]
        ,SIL.[Description]
        ,SIL.[Service Item Group Code]
        ,SIL.[Serial No_]
        ,SH.[Address]
        ,SH.[City]
        ,[No_]
        ,CASE SIL.[Claim] 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Ja' 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Nee'   END [Claim] 
        FROM  
        [dbo].[cache\$Service Header] SH INNER JOIN 
        [cache\$Service Item Line] SIL ON SH.[Document Type] = SIL.[document type] AND SH.[No_] = SIL.[Document No_] 
        WHERE [Repair Status Code] = '53'";

$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params,$options);

if (!sqlsrv_num_rows($result)) {
    echo 'No records found';
} else {
    ?>
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Garantie</th>
        <th>Serviceordernummer</th>
        <th>Referentie</th>
        <th>Serviceartikelgroepcode</th>
        <th>Omschrijving</th>
        <th>Serienummer</th>
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>Adres</th>
        <th>Plaats</th>
        <th>Ruilkaart</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo'<tr>'; 
    echo'<td>'.$row['Claim'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['No_'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Your Reference'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Service Item Group Code'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Description'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Serial No_'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['Address'].'</td>';                          
    echo'<td>'.$row['City'].'</td>'; 
    echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"ruilkaart\" class=\"radio\" value=\"ruilkaart\"></td>";
    echo'<tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php 
}
?>
```